# Trying to redirect an url based on a pattern but failed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect an url like this `http://domain.com/2011/09/rugs-from-therese-sennerholt/comment-page-1/` to the index page `http://domain.com/`.

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/comment-page-(.*)/ $1/ [L,R=301,L]
```

But not working it is still pointing to a 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this rule as **your very first rule** just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/comment-page- /? [L,R=301]
```